extension context invalidated issue requires reload of current chrome tab for content scripts to work
when i reload my extension from chrome://extensions and then after that i go to any chrome tab and try to run my extension then i get error "extension context invalidated" , to avoid this error i need to reload my chrome tabs after reloading the extension and then extension works perfectly fine.
My extension has a popup and on that popup i have a button named 'click',when i click on that button then a contentScript named record.js runs which is called in popup.js as ---
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document
    .getElementById("bugs-work-settingsBtn")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
          files: ["record.js"],
        });
    });
});

and that contentScript after doing it's work, further calls another contentScript named content.js as---
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("executeContentScript"));
in content.js my code starts as---
    chrome.storage.local.get(["savedUrl"], function (result) {
      var x = result.savedUrl;
      appendSentence(x, "ss");
  });
});```

and after that appendSentence function gets called .
But in case of extension reload the content.js gets called but then 
at 
```chrome.storage.local.get(["savedUrl"], function (result) {
...}```
the very first line after being called, i get error as "extension contextr invalidated" which as far as i know comes because the connection of exsiting content.js got broke from extension because of extension reload. So how to make this process smooth so that no matter the extension is reloaded or installed the entire flow from popup to record and record to content should run smoothly without any error.

i can get in background.js which is a background script file , that when my extension is getting reloaded or installed using this i tried to communicate with my content scipts from backkground after extension reload but since the extension context has been invalidated so communication always fails and i am not able to create a smooth user exprience.



```chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  if (details.reason === "install" || details.reason === "update") {
    console.log(details.reason)
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  console.log(isExtensionValid)
});```



You need to unregister listeners in the invalidated context. Why do you have two content scripts, how did you inject or declared the second script?

@wOxxOm how do i unregister listeners?

@wOxxOm One content script is to perform one part of task and then the output of that task is further processed in second content script , and i can't merge second one with first because second content script is kind of a reusable script for other scenarios as well. also the second one i inject using the code --
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("executeContentScript")); in first one i write this

and in second one it runs as
function executeContentScriptHandler() {
loadLibJs(function () {
chrome.storage.local.get(["savedUrl"], function (result) {
var savedUrl = result.savedUrl;
appendSentence(savedUrl, "imgFinal");
});
});
document.removeEventListener(
"executeContentScript",
executeContentScriptHandler
);
}
document.addEventListener(
"executeContentScript",
executeContentScriptHandler
);

@wOxxOm can you please tell me how do i handle this scenario because after extension is reloaded first content script works totally fine but in second one the chrome apis like chrome.runtime.getURL(...) etc., are failing , in first content script everything works perfect even after reload .
i tried injecting both the content scripts altogether and then calling second one from first one as stated above still second one doesn't work


Assuming you didn't specify a different world, there's no need for CustomEvent, you can simply call the global functions directly from other script. 2) If you declare in manifest.json, you need to re-inject content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome.


@wOxxOm ok now assume i am injecting my content script file from popup.js as-
chrome.scripting.executeScript({         target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },         files: ["content.js"],       });
and this then never gives any context invalidated error but  i want to pass some parameter to my content script if i inject mycontent script using
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {         action: "request_perform",       }); 
then i can pass param but it gives extension context invalidated on extension reload what to do?

Instead of sendMessage you can run executeScript with args: ['yourdata'], func: v => {window.params = v} and then executeScript for the content script, which will use window.params.
